# Upgrading Kernel 3.13.0-83 on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS?

Tags: kernel, updates

I have a Ubuntu Root since years and sometimes upgraded the Ubuntu version whenever my hosting provider offered an update or if I was brave enough to update it.

Anyway, as of now it acts as a private webspace for my family and friends and runs Parallels Plesk 12.5

Plesk has no support for Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS so far,so that means I have to stick with 14.04.5 LTS.

As you can see from the topic title, the kernel is rather outdated. If i run apt-get update and apt-get upgrade, it helds back all packages for kernel updates, which are:

linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic

I only learned about APT (not APT-GET) today and ran apt upgrade and there it offered me to update to the following kernel:

linux-headers-3.13.0-100 linux-headers-3.13.0-100-generic linux-image-3.13.0-100 generic and linux-image-extra-3.13.0-100-generic.

I have been out of the loop for a while and I'm slightly confused.

Should I stick to apt-get upgrade and let it tell me, that it keeps those updates back or should I trust apt and let it install those updates? Is dist-upgrade another solution?

PS:

I mostly got to updating the kernel, since I just read about a privilege-escalation bug within the kernel.

Cheers,

Maxunit

Comment: Either you use `apt` or `apt-get` you will get the offer to update the kernel with both commands. and you should perform the upgrade. Please take a look at [the answer in this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/839919/what-is-dirty-cow-bug-that-allows-local-user-to-gain-administrative-access/839920#839920)

Comment: You can install kernel updates with `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`