# Dist upgrade to fix dirty c0w vulnerability does not work

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

Today I decided to follow the steps to patch my server from the dirty c0w vulnerability.

It's running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS:

```
uname -rv
3.2.0-87-generic #125-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 19 08:25:10 UTC 2015
uname -a
Linux webdev 3.2.0-87-generic #125-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 19 08:25:10 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

So, as every version prior to 3.2.0-113.155 are affected, I've ran the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Everything went fine, I rebooted:

```
sudo reboot
```

But now that I check my version, it has not changed:

```
uname -rv
3.2.0-87-generic #125-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 19 08:25:10 UTC 2015
```

Did I miss something ? I double checked and I didn't get any error during during the upgrade.

### Edit based on comments / answers

I ran `sudo update-grub` and got the following:

```
Generating grub.cfg ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-87-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-87-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-86-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-86-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-85-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-85-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-84-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-84-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-83-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-83-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-82-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-82-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-80-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-80-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-79-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-79-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-38-server
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-38-server
Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.bin
done
```

After a reboot still no change.

Ran `dpkg --get-selections | grep linux` and got:

```
libselinux1                                     install
linux-firmware                                  install
linux-headers-3.2.0-101                         install
linux-headers-3.2.0-101-generic                 install
linux-headers-3.2.0-102                         install
linux-headers-3.2.0-102-generic                 install
linux-headers-3.2.0-104                         install
linux-headers-3.2.0-104-generic                 install
linux-headers-3.2.0-106                         install
linux-headers-3.2.0-106-generic                 install
linux-headers-3.2.0-107                         install
linux-headers-3.2.0-107-generic                 install
linux-headers-3.2.0-109                         install
linux-headers-3.2.0-109-generic                 install
linux-headers-3.2.0-110                         install
linux-headers-3.2.0-110-generic                 install
linux-headers-3.2.0-111                         install
linux-headers-3.2.0-111-generic                 install
linux-headers-3.2.0-113                         install
linux-headers-3.2.0-113-generic                 install
linux-headers-3.2.0-86                          install
linux-headers-3.2.0-86-generic                  install
linux-headers-3.2.0-87                          install
linux-headers-3.2.0-87-generic                  install
linux-headers-3.2.0-89                          install
linux-headers-3.2.0-89-generic                  install
linux-headers-3.2.0-91                          install
linux-headers-3.2.0-91-generic                  install
linux-headers-3.2.0-92                          install
linux-headers-3.2.0-92-generic                  install
linux-headers-3.2.0-93                          install
linux-headers-3.2.0-93-generic                  install
linux-headers-3.2.0-94                          install
linux-headers-3.2.0-94-generic                  install
linux-headers-3.2.0-95                          install
linux-headers-3.2.0-95-generic                  install
linux-headers-3.2.0-96                          install
linux-headers-3.2.0-96-generic                  install
linux-headers-3.2.0-97                          install
linux-headers-3.2.0-97-generic                  install
linux-headers-3.2.0-98                          install
linux-headers-3.2.0-98-generic                  install
linux-headers-3.2.0-99                          install
linux-headers-3.2.0-99-generic                  install
linux-headers-server                            install
linux-image-2.6.32-38-server                    install
linux-image-3.2.0-79-generic                    install
linux-image-3.2.0-80-generic                    install
linux-image-3.2.0-82-generic                    install
linux-image-3.2.0-83-generic                    install
linux-image-3.2.0-84-generic                    install
linux-image-3.2.0-85-generic                    install
linux-image-3.2.0-86-generic                    install
linux-image-3.2.0-87-generic                    install
linux-libc-dev                                  install
util-linux                                      install
```

Seems like there is no new linux images in that list.

However, when I ran `sudo apt-cache policy linux-image-generic` it listed the new version as a candidate (it's in french but you get it):

```
linux-image-generic:
  InstallÃ©Â : (aucun)
  CandidatÂ : 3.2.0.113.129
 Table de versionÂ :
     3.2.0.113.129 0
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
     3.2.0.23.25 0
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: What's the output of `apt-cache policy linux-image-generic`?

Comment: @Ron see my edit

Comment: @Ron thanks to your comment, I found a way, see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I finally managed to upgrade.

Here's how I did it.

Based on Ron comment on my answer I decided to run:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic
```

That failed because of my `/boot` being full so I got rid of old versions by running:

```
sudo dpkg -r linux-image-3.2.0-79-generic
sudo dpkg -r linux-image-3.2.0-80-generic
sudo dpkg -r linux-image-3.2.0-82-generic
sudo dpkg -r linux-image-3.2.0-84-generic
sudo dpkg -r linux-image-3.2.0-85-generic
```

After that I ran:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade -f
```

Then reboot:

```
sudo reboot
```

And now, I'm running a "safe" version:

```
uname -rv
3.2.0-113-generic #155-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 18 17:53:59 UTC 2016
```

However, I still have no idea why running the following never worked:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: To answer your last question, my hunch is because `/boot` was full, automatic kernel updates stopped after revision `87`...

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix that's what I assumed too, I just found it weird that I never got the `/boot is full` error until I ran `sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic
`

Answer (score 2):

Your `uname -rv` reveals your current kernel as:

```
3.2.0-87-generic #125-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 19 08:25:10 UTC 2015
```

The date is June 19, 2015 -- over one year old!

According to this: [What is dirty COW bug that allows local user to gain administrative access?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/839919/what-is-dirty-cow-bug-that-allows-local-user-to-gain-administrative-access) you should be using `3.2.0-113` I'm not sure how many kernel upgrades you've missed, but probably lots over 16 months (subtracting 87 from 113 = 26).

Since everyone and their dog in the Linux world has heard about `Dirty COW` by now you should put version **3.2.0-113** in ASAP. Until you find out why your Kernel hasn't been upgrading you can install the kernel manually. You didn't use `uname -a` so it's unknown if you are on 32-bit or 64-bit but I'll give the instructions for both.

## Install Dirty COW fix for Ubuntu 32-Bit Generic

Go to: [precise-updates/i386/linux-image-3.2.0-113](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise-updates/i386/linux-image-3.2.0-113-generic/download) and select the link for your country to download the file. Your browser may give you a warning message. In Chrome click `Keep`.

The file is usually downloaded to your `~/Downloads` directory but your browser can be user-configured for any location. We'll assume it's `~/Downloads` so type the following:

```
cd ~/Downloads
sudo dpkg -i linux-image-3.2.0-113-generic_3.2.0-113.155_i386.deb
rm linux-image-3.2.0-113-generic_3.2.0-113.155_i386.deb
sudo reboot
```

## Install Dirty COW fix for Ubuntu 64-Bit Generic

Go to: [precise-updates/amd64/linux-image-3.2.0-113](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise-updates/amd64/linux-image-3.2.0-113-generic/download) and select the link for your country to download the file. Your browser may give you a warning message. In Chrome click `Keep`.

The file is usually downloaded to your `~/Downloads` directory but your browser can be user-configured for any location. We'll assume it's `~/Downloads` so type the following:

```
cd ~/Downloads
sudo dpkg -i linux-image-3.2.0-113-generic_3.2.0-113.155_amd64.deb
rm linux-image-3.2.0-113-generic_3.2.0-113.155_amd64.deb
sudo reboot
```

---

After rebooting type `uname -a` to confirm you are on Kernel version `3.2.0-113`.

Comment: See my edited question. Any way I can upgrade the dist without having to manually download as you suggested based on the commands I ran ?

Comment: Got it working, see my answer

Answer (score 1):

Maybe GRUB was not updated properly after running the commands.
Execute : `sudo update-grub`. Reboot the system and check it again.

In case the old kernel booted again, check whether the new was installed :
Execute the following command : `dpkg --get-selections | grep linux`

Comment: See my edited question

Comment: Got it working see my answer

Comment: @RaphPetrini : I was just about to update my answer with these instructions ... I am glad that you solved it, but I would have suggested to purge all old headers and images except for the current and the one before to have a clean setup : sudo apt purge linux-headers-X linux-headers-X-generic linux-image-X-generic | ... note : replace X with the version numbers ! :)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I actually tried using `sudo apt purge` for those old headers. The command worked but my `boot` folder was still full. Using `dpkg -r` solved my issue