# vboxdrv: Fatal error in Kernel 4.8

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, virtualization

Why the `modprobe vboxdrv` is not resolved yet for Kernel 4.8?

I have 2 kernels 4.4 and 4.8 and `vboxdrv` is working fine on 4.4 but whenever i try to launch my vm i get a fatal error with `modprobe vboxdrv`.

Should I wait for a Virtualbox update is it can be fixed somehow for the newest Kernel?

EDIT: this is my uname-a output

```
Linux mohsen-SVP1322F4E 4.8.1-040801-generic #201610071031 SMP Fri Oct 7 14:34:10 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

EDIT2: Updated to kernel 4.8.4 and then removed the virtualbox dkms then reinstall it again. Still the error is found. Vboxdrv is still not found.

EDIT3: Tried to reinstall the virtualbox dkms with no luck. Then removed and reinstalled Virtualbox as per [here](https://www.linuxbabe.com/virtualbox/install-latest-virtualbox-5-1-ubuntu-16-04) and everything is working fine now.

Comment: Can you update your question with the output from 'uname -a'?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix yes i will now

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix i did it!

Comment: You can try Kernel 4.8.4 to see if that works.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix ok then I'll update it and let you know

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix i updated to 4.8.4 but still it gives the the same error. modprobe: FATAL: Module vboxdrv not found in directory /lib/modules/4.8.4-040804-generic

Comment: I did a quick google and it looks like you need to compile it for 4.8.

Comment: Yes exactly. I did update my question for how i fixed it.

Comment: Yes I just saw that. Congrats.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix please if u can submit a summary for an answer so it can be votes as this problem is encountered by many.

Comment: I will do that as soon as I get home 1 hour Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Oracle's Virtual Box 5.1 the DKMS (Dynamic Kernel Management System) is no longer used to download source code and compile it for every Kernel Upgrade.

Go to [Install latest VirtualBox 5.1 Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.linuxbabe.com/virtualbox/install-latest-virtualbox-5-1-ubuntu-16-04) for instructions on:

- removing old version
- adding VirtualBox to sources.list (informs Ubuntu where to find it)
- adding VirtualBox signature key to library
- installing current version of VirtualBox

Also instead of Kernel version 4.8.1 which has the "Dirty COW" security holes ([What is dirty COW bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/839919/what-is-dirty-cow-bug-that-allows-local-user-to-gain-administrative-access)), you should use the most recent kernel version 4.8.4 (as of October 27, 2016) which has the bug fix.