# How to downgrade to nautilus 3.14 from nautilus 3.18

Tags: nautilus

My Ubuntu 16.04 suddenly upgraded to nautilus 3.18. Is there anyway to downgrade back to 3.14?

Comment: Please post results of `apt-cache policy nautilus` 3.18 is possibly from a ppa

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04:

[image: Ubuntu Version]

and I just received updates yesterday but Nautilus version is still:

[image]

From what I've read it's difficult to run a different version of Nautilus with a specific Ubuntu version, they are tightly married.

Comment: I was trying to upgrade to kernel 4.8.7.  It all started after i typed dist upgrade

Comment: Yup you just upgraded to Ubuntu 16.10 which uses kernel 4.8.0.  See this answer which describes how to upgrade to 4.8.5 kernel and you need to massage the instructions for 4.8.7: http://askubuntu.com/questions/839919/what-is-dirty-cow-bug-and-how-do-i-protect-against-that-bug/839920#839920

Comment: I'm still using ubuntu 16.04 according to About this computer section

Comment: Is your kernel still at 4.4.0-47? Use `uname -r` to find out.

Comment: I have 4.8.7 and also 4.4.0-47. No i switched to 4.4.0-47

Comment: You can do `sudo apt-get remove nautilus` and `sudo apt-get install nautilus` but we want to freeze the package at version 3.14.3 before installing to make sure 3.18 doesn't get installed again. I'm trying some google searches. Also others performing dist-upgrade might report the same problems soon.